# Ошибка 403 ISP Manager Cs Cart

Tags: php, apache2, ispmanager

Здравствуйте Уважаемые форумчане.
Возникла следующая проблема.
Не могу в браузере открыть любые php файлы отличные от главной страницы.
Например site.com/app/addons/yandex/fnc.php - вылетает 403 ошибка.
Везде поставил права 777.
Сервер на apache2.
В логах `[Wed Mar 30 15:23:21 2016] [error] [client 176.209.200.98] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/andrey/data/www/andrey.devstyle.ru/app`
Можно ли это исправить используя Isp Manager или .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, в папке app был еще один файл .htaccess, который закрывал доступ.

Answer (score 0):

включите отображение ошибок [php.net error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php)